# APNS push notification, string key in loc-args

Tags: ios, localization, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I'm trying to populate the 'alert' portion of a push notification with keys to some localized strings in an iOS app. Providing the key to the appropriate string in the 'loc-key' property does what it's supposed to and works great. However, I'd also like to provide a key to a localized string in the 'loc-args' property. When testing, putting the key in 'loc-args' displays the key in the notification on the phone, not the string that the key points at.

Here's an example payload:
`{"aps":{"alert":{"loc-key":"STRING_KEY","loc-args":["ANOTHER_KEY"]}}}`

Is what I'm trying to accomplish possible at all? Been searching around and I haven't seen this discussed anywhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nested localization is not supported.

You would need to have the STRING_KEY handle the mapping and pass two strings in the loc-args array.

Comment: Just for reference, can you share the link of documentation where Apple mentioned this ? Is there any other option to achieve this ?

Comment: It's all documented in the Local and Push Notification Programming Guide.  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html

Comment: I know this answer is old, but it would be so great to see an example of how to do it!

Comment: Found a solution that is suitable here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32866886/8490899