# Send localized string key in loc-args for iOS Push notifications

Tags: ios7, apple-push-notifications, nslocalizedstring, localizable.strings

My application supports 4 languages & push notifications. When I send push notification to APNS , I am sending `loc_key` & `loc-args`. Now I need to send localized strings in `loc-args` array so that I can translate those on iOS app side when app receives the push notification.

But when I send localized strings in `loc-args` , instead of showing translated string in notification center , it just showed localized key as it is.

My string file contains below 2 messages:

```
"WINNER_ALERT"= "Congratulations! %@ won the match & became %@ player";
"ROLE_PROFESSIONAL_LOCALIZED_KEY" = "professional"
```

Server sends below payload

```
{
    aps =     {
        alert =         {
            "loc-args" =             (
                "John",
                "ROLE_PROFESSIONAL_LOCALIZED_KEY"
            );
            "loc-key" = "WINNER_ALERT";
        };
        badge = 1;
        sound = default;
    };
}
```

When I send above payload then in iOS Notification Center , message look like

```
Congratulations! John won the match & became ROLE_PROFESSIONAL_LOCALIZED_KEY player
```

instead of

```
Congratulations! JOHN won the match & became professional player
```

Can anyone tell me whether it is possible to send localized strings in `loc-args` ? If yes, what's wrong in my payload ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't send localization keys in loc-args

Comment: have you got the solution ?

Answer (score 7):

I believe your `Localizable.strings` file should look like this :

```
"WINNER_ALERT"= "Congratulations! %@ won the match & became %@ player";
```

And the push notification payload should look like this :

```
{
    aps =     {
        alert =         {
            "loc-args" = (
                "JOHN",
                "professional"
            );
            "loc-key" = "WINNER_ALERT";
        };
        badge = 1;
        sound = default;
    };
}
```

This will give the desired result :

`Congratulations! JOHN won the match & became professional player`

---

**Here's why** (according to [Apple's Local and Remote Notification Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW1)) :

- `loc-key` : A key to an alert-message string in a Localizable.strings file for the current localization
- `loc-args` : Variable string values to appear in place of the format specifiers in loc-key

Answer (score 7):

@Zak answer's works like a charm.

Furthermore, if you need `professional` to be localised, it should be part of `WINNER_ARERT` string.

If you need to pass different strings for `professional`, you should create several localised strings. E.G. :

1) `"WINNER_ALERT_PROFESSIONAL"= "Congratulations! %@ won the match & became professional player";`

2) `"WINNER_ALERT_SEMI_PROFESSIONAL"= "Congratulations! %@ won the match & became semi-professional player";`

Comment: This should have been a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).